Is the Fubini-Study metric Riemannian? Or Hermitian?
I have a question about the Fubini-Study metric, which is given in the local coordinate frame $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z^i}\}$ by
$$g_{i \bar{j}} = \frac{(1+|z|^2)\delta_{ij}+\overline z^i z^j}{(1+|z|^2)^2}.$$
I have seen the Fubini-Study metric referred to as a Kähler metric which is, in particular, a Riemannian metric. The problem here though is that $g_{i \bar j}: U \to \mathbb{C}$, so $g$ isn't actually Riemannian. Further, I've also seen $g$ referred to as a Hermitian metric, which has completely thrown me off. What am I missing here?

No, a Kähler metric is a hermitian metric. That, in turn, induces a Riemannian metric.

@TedShifrin So let me get this right: the above expression gives a Hermitian fibre metric on the complexified tangent bundle. Then, taking the real part of this expression gives the Riemannian metric?

Yes, to the second. For the first, most people think of this as a hermitian metric on the holomorphic tangent bundle itself. Interpret $d\bar z^j(v) = \overline{dz^j(v)}$.

@TedShifrin Ahh I see, so it can be interpreted that $g_p : T^{1,0} X \times T^{0,1} X \to \mathbb{C}$ (where $X := \mathbb{CP}^n$).... is the whole point of construction a Hermitian fibre metric on $T^{1,0}X$ to make sure that we can get the Chern connection? Because there's not much geometry we can do with $g$, right?

You still need to think about what a Hermitian metric on a complex vector space is. Certainly one point of a hermitian metric on a holomorphic vector bundle is that then you can think of the unique Chern connection as analogous to the Levi-Civita connection on the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold. But a hermitian metric may well have other uses.

This helps a lot, thank you!
